# Python Selenium How to select 1st row text from multiple texts in one tag

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to select the 1st row text on the attached photo:

[image]

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[role=option]').text
```

When I print above code,
It returns
1st row + 2nd row together ; 진로 두꺼비 피규어 (+600원)
But I want a 1st row text only. ; 진로 두꺼비 피규어

How can I select the 1st row text from the multiple texts in one tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[role=option]')
ele_value = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[1].textContent;", ele)
print(ele_value)
```